# Can Reed Solomon parity blocks be used as an all-or-nothing transform?

Tags: encoding, coding-theory, aont

Consider the following scheme:

1. Perform an (N,N) Reed-Solomon encoding (i.e. N data blocks, N parity blocks)
2. Drop the N data blocks and keep only the N parity blocks.

Are these N parity blocks an all-or-nothing transform? (meaning missing even one parity block does not permit decoding the original data blocks)

Comment: does my answer address your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reed-Solomon codes are Maximum-Distance-Separable codes and thus have the property that in a $[n,k]$ RS code ---- meaning than there are a *total* of $n$ blocks of which $k$ are data blocks and $n-k$ are parity block ($n=2N$ and $k=N$ in the OP's notation) ---- *any* $k$ blocks are sufficient to reconstruct the entire codeword, that is, *all* the blocks can be found if we know $k$ of them. Note that it does not matter whether the $k$ blocks available are a mixture of data and parity blocks or parity blocks only, just as long as $k$ blocks are available.

So, in the scheme envisioned by the OP, if one has a $[2N,N]$ Reed-Solomon code ($N$ data blocks, $N$ parity blocks, for a total of $2N$ blocks) and keeps only the $N$ parity blocks, the $N$ data blocks can be reconstructed. If fewer than $N$ of the parity blocks, then the data blocks *cannot* be reconstructed in the sense that the decoder can come up with a *list* of $M$ possible candidates for the $N$ data blocks but cannot say *which* of the candidates is the correct one.  Here, *each* of the $M$ candidates on the *list* is a *vector* $[D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_N]$
of $N$ data block (each $D_i$ is a data block) and the decoder cannot determine which is the correct vector of $N$ data blocks. What is $M$?  Well, $M$ is the number of possible distinct values that each data block might have and thus is either the number of elements in the finite field over which the Reed-Solomon code is defined, or some power $L$ thereof if each data block is a vector of length $L$ over the finite field (and we are using an interleaved Reed-Solomon code). Either way, $M$ is pretty large.

Comment: Thank you @dilip, the answer is clear. As a side question, imagine that I want to add an extra constraint to my problem : "The $N$ data blocks should be reconstructed exclusively from the $N$ parity blocks, and not from a mixture of data and parity blocks". Would Reed-Solomon (non-systematic?) still be a candidate for this constrained scheme?

Comment: @stefanix As I said in my answer, it does not matter to the general (erasures-correcting) decoding algorithm whether the $N$ available blocks are parity blocks only or a mixture of data and parity blocks. But it is certainly possible to modify the general algorithm to tell it to refuse to decode a mixture of data and parity blocks, and decode iff $N$ parity blocks are available. Similarly, when $<N$ blocks are available, the standard RS decoder fails to decode (gives error signal only), and it is necessary to re-program it to spit out the list of $M$ possible vectors of data blocks instead.

Answer (score 0):

A Reed-Solomon code is an MDS code over the symbol alphabet $\mathbb{F}_q,$ with parameters $[n,k,n-k+1]$. Here, the length $n=2N$ the dimension $k=N$ and the minimum distance is $d=N+1.$

Such codes form Orthogonal Arrays of strength $t=n-d+1=N+1.$

And an OA of strength $t$ is also an OA of strength $t'\leq t.$ Take $t'=N.$  Thus, yes, dropping one of the $N$ parity blocks would result in an AONT, leaking no information about the missing block.

**Edit:** In general *any* $N$ blocks are enough to reconstruct the missing blocks.

Comment: Just to make sure: dropping one of the N parity blocks does not leak any information on any of the N data blocks?

Comment: So how many blocks do you need in total to reconstruct the data?

Comment: My comment above is in error, I will edit the body of the paper, to stop the confusion.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect even after the edit.

Comment: OK, much better after the second edit.